# Trying to understand what is happening here with static_cast?

Tags: c++, static-cast

I'm working on an old C++ project, in the source there are two lines:

```
memcpy( static_cast<PLONADDRESS>(this), pa, sizeof(LONADDRESS) );
memcpy( static_cast<PLONIOFILTER)(this), pf, sizeof(LONIOFILTER) );
```

`this` is an object of type CLonFilterUnit, it is derived from public classes:

```
class CLonFilterUnit : public LONADDRESS, public LONIOFILTER
```

`PLONADDRESS` is:

```
typedef LONADDRESS* PLONADRESS;
```

`PLONFILTER` is:

```
typedef LONIOFILTER* PLONFILTER;
```

`pa` is of type `PLONADDRESS` and `pf` is of type `PLONIOFILTER`.

What I don't understand is how the same base address is used as the destination in both `memcpy` instructions?  Is this permitted due to the way `static_cast` works?

Comment: So what's `LONADDRESS` ?

Comment: The class has multiple base classes, the `static_cast` is returning the address of each of the different base classes. `memcpy` into a C++ class isn't generally a good idea though.

Comment: @JonathanPotter, thats my thinking exactly...I'm trying to understand it because it looks like a bad design.

Comment: @RichardCritten, does it matter what LONADDRESS is?  Its a class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you have a class that is derived from multiple base classes those classes can be thought of as sub objects of the derived class.  You will have a base1, base2, ..., baseN part of the derived object.  When you `static_cast` a pointer to the derived class to a pointer of one of its base classes the cast will adjust the pointer to point to the correct base (sub object) of the object.  You can see that with this little example:

```
struct foo
{
    int a;
};

struct bar
{
    int b;
};

struct foobar : foo, bar {};

int main() {
    foobar f;
    std::cout << static_cast<foo*>(&f) << "\t" << static_cast<bar*>(&f);
}
```

output:

```
0x7ffe250056c8  0x7ffe250056cc
```

<kbd>[live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2e89c429b8a5777d)</kbd>

---

I would also like to point out that if your class is not trivially copyable then the code has undefined behavior as `memcpy` requires that.

Comment: Others have suggested that using memcpy with static_cast isn't a good idea, can you say why?

Comment: @SPlatten It is code smell and you lose all type safety.  Ideally you should have a `operator=` defined for your class and a construct that takes it base parts and then you can just write `myObject = CLonFilterUnit(base1, base2);`

Answer (score 0):

`static_cast` does the necessary address adjustment.

The code (with `memcpy`, uppercase names, typedefs of pointers) is a great example of how to absolutely not do things. Maybe it's used as an example in a lecture series about how to lose your job quickly.

Comment: What is the downside of this approach?  If the language performs as described why is it a bad thing?  I'm not disagreeing just want to understand.

Comment: It's extremely brittle code. Perhaps it was originally correct, then some maintainer comes along and introduces a virtual function in one of the classes. Wham, you have udefined behavior, which might go unnoticed until it causes a million-dollar problem for a client.

Comment: @SPlatten for one, because you had to ask :)

Comment: @deW1, isn't that what comments are for?  Just because something isn't obvious isn't a good enough reason for not using it....it that were true most of C++ would be taboo.

Comment: @SPlatten I mean the downside is. you having to ask a question, because it's that badly maintaineable.

Comment: @deW1, agreed, but then once I know and understand how the static_cast works I can work with it...or around it.

Answer (score -1):

This is an example of some extremely dubious C++ code. I can hardly imagine why this code would be necessary - most likely, it is not.

However, to answer the question as asked, the way multiple inheritance works in C++ is by having different 'subobjects' of different base classes within the derived class. Those subobjects do not have the same address. By using `static_cast` on `this`, you select one subobject or another, and results of `static_cast` yield different addresses.

Comment: The original source was written over ten years ago, by a developer who is no longer on the scene....the end product is still in use today and needs updating to stay current...thats the job I'm lumbered with.